# How to make Apache "translate" HTTP requests into HTTPS requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I have a website that I don't want to be used over HTTP. How can I make Apache redirect all HTTP requests to `https://mysite`?

Comment: This seems to be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816119/using-mod-rewrite-how-do-i-force-https-for-certain-paths-and-http-for-all-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the config for your port 80 `VirtualHost`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://mysite/ [R=301]
```

If you want to keep the url path that was entered, you can do this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: What does `[R=301]` mean?

Comment: It means to send a 301 status code with the redirect, which means "permanent".  The default, when you don't specify (using just `[R]`) is to send a 302 status code, which indicates "found" - the real-world difference is debatable, but sending a 301 is the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: By the way, sorry for the delay, I thought I had already accepted your answer.